# Java : retrieve the min and max age object array of records from the list of object array

Tags: java

I have a list of object arrays. the Object array has the values "Name" & "age"

```
list 1
object arrray 1 -- ["AAA", 28]
list 2
object arrray 2 -- ["BBB", 25]
list 3
object arrray 3 -- ["CCC", 29]
list 4
object arrray 4 -- ["DDD", 18]
list 5
object arrray 5 -- ["EEE", 20]
```

I need to get the min and max age records as mentioned below,

```
result:

["CCC", 29] - max age
["DDD", 18] - min age
```

can i know how to get those result

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

```
public class CompareAge implements Comparator<YourObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
        return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
    }
}
```

Then after, Sort it and retrieve the last and first object from `ArrayList` of `Object`

```
  Collections.sort(myArrayList, new CompareAge());
  YourObject maxAgeObj = myArrayList.get(myArrayList.size() - 1); //Retrieve the last object
  YourObject minAgeObj =  myArrayList.get(0);
```

Comment: `Object` doesn't have a `getAge` method. And `Comparator` isn't an `interface`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I assume It's a POJO having name and age as it's properties Just expressed it as Object.

Comment: OP says it's a list of an array of objects. So I don't think that's a safe assumption. Note the numbering of "object array"(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I really appreciate your suggestions, But S(he) can find the pattern useful. I'll edit soon after getting some time Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
List objects;

int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxIndexOuter = -1;
int minIndexOuter = -1;
int maxIndexInner = -1;
int minIndexInner = -1;

for(int i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++){
 for(int x = 0 ; x < objects[i].length ; x++){
  if(objects[i][x].age > max){
   max = objects[i][x].age;
   maxIndexOuter = i;
   maxIndexInner = x;
  }
  if(objects[i][x].age < min){
   min = objects[i][x].age;
   minIndexOuter = i;
   minIndexInner = x;
  }
 }
}
```

- You could use then IndexOuter and IndexInner to reach the inner array object.